# How to set bootstrap div not to be collapsed by default

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel which is shown or hidden on click (collapse). When I load the page it is set to be hidden by default? How can I change this?

```
<div class="col-md-1">
<a style="float:right;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
...
```

Also, how can I change this glyphicon icon to `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down`?

Comment: this will be help u.. https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/KLAcm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class `in` to your collapsable div:

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapsing in">
```

Comment: Thx ... btw `<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapsing in">` .. collapse instead of collapsing works

Comment: Of course.. Just need a few more seconds to pass so I can accept it. Please edit your answer to `<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">`

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me in bootstrap 4.3.1 was to use the `.show` class:

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse show">
```